# Filtering DataFrame by column value in comparison to dictionary value?

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have a DataFrame, for simplicity reason let's say it has only two columns:
'Date created' and 'Responsible Market'. I also have a dictionary called launch_dates, whose keys are countries that correspond to the 'Responsible Market' column and it's values are dates on which the country had it's product launch.

I now want to filter the DataFrame, so that only rows exist whose 'Date Created' was after the launch date off their responsible market.

I have tried this:

```
df = df.loc[df['Case created on - Date'] >= launch_dates.get(df.loc['Responsible Market'])]
```

But it gives me

```
KeyError: 'Responsible Market'
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df = df.loc[df['Case created on - Date'] >= df['Responsible Market'].map(launch_dates)]
```